# Will push notification work on my old app if I update push notification certificate?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I have an ios and android app live , developed on ionic .
My ios push notification certificate is expiring in nov. I ahve talked to few developers they said we need to create and update new certificate. 
 1. My only issue is if we update new certificate will the old user still be able to get the push notifications ?
 2. Do we need to update the ipa version on apple store?

Answer (score 1):

The last time i updated my push-notifications-certificate everything worked fine. For my understanding the certificate is only for the connecting and authorizing so that no one else can send notifications to your apps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update the IPA on the store in order for the new certificate to work. I've done this a few times. You have nothing to worry about.

The certificate is to authenticate your push notifications server with APNS, and it has nothing to do with the IPA, as long as your bundle identifier doesn't change between certificates.

Answer (score -1):

No need to create the new ipa ... Actually i have used SNS service of AWS, my certificate was about to expire, i have uploaded the new certificate and everything work like charm ..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17640264)

Comment: @Patrick just edited my answer, may be this will help to asker :)